# JMX Monitoring using Zabbix

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx, zabbix

I need to see what memory size, CPU usage and so on for my application, found [zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) as monitoring tool and want to create bridge between zabbix and my app. I do not want to add additional module with JMX MBeans. Are there some implementations/solution for creating bridges ? I wanna copy some jar/jars o my class path and see general monitoring information.
Thank a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is also possible to use the beta release of Zabbix 2.0 (Beta release is 1.9) which will allow you to use the [Java Gateway](http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/concepts/java?s%5B%5D=java) as a bridge. This does require running another service, however it does allow you to have remote java processes monitored behind various firewalls that you don't want direct JMX exposure to.

The documentation for the JMX monitoring is [here](http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/jmx_monitoring?s%5B%5D=java)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is one named Zapcat. I used it. It is simple to install and works fine.

http://www.kjkoster.org/zapcat/Zapcat_JMX_Zabbix_Bridge.html

http://sourceforge.net/projects/zapcat/

Answer (score 1):

Take care, JMX monitoring makes Zabbix server crashes in 2.0.1!!!
https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-5206

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [JMX Proxy servlet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html#Using_the_JMX_Proxy_Servlet) or write your own if the default one doesn't do what you want.

Zabbix should be able to retrieve the data via HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

[Jolokia](https://jolokia.org) or [hawtio](http://hawt.io) can be used here.